# jQuery get value from form returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I've come across multiple answers to this question and have not found one that works. I am using pug(jade) and trying to get the value from a modal form.

here is the pug:

```
     #myModal.modal.fade(tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria-labelledby='myModalLabel',data-keyboard="false", data-backdrop="static")
   .modal-dialog(role='document')
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        .text-center.h4#myModalLabel.modal-title(style="color:#4c86ff; font-family: 'Lora', serif; font-size:20px; font-weight:600") please add your symptoms
      .modal-body
        form.form-horizontal(action='/token' ,id='symptoms', method='POST')
          input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value=_csrf)
          .form-group
              input.textarea.form-control(type='text', name='symptomsInput', id='symptomsInput', placeholder='What are your symptoms?', autofocus, required)
      .modal-footer
        button.btn.btn-primary#button-grabToke(type='submit' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal") Go!
```

and here is my js:

```
$('#button-grabToke').click(function(e){
     var symptoms = $('#DynamicValueAssignedHere').find('input[name="symptomsInput"]').val();
      console.log(symptoms);
         }); 
});
```

Comment: so what is `DynamicValueAssignedHere`? Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think i can find the problem without knowing where #DynamicValueAssignedHere is.  But on thing, i think its easier on jquery to find(an id) rather than a input[name:

```
find('#symptomsInput').val();
```

check your browser debugging and make sure #DynamicValueAssignedHere is a decendant of #symptomsInput.  I bet its not.

Comment: think you mean "is an ancestor" not "is descendant"

Comment: Thank you, I figured it'd be a bone headed mistake